# Guice injection failing with guice annotation module

Tags: java, timer, annotations, guice

I'm using google guice injection most of my code and it has been working fine **until I made a google guice annotation**.

The code itself is a **jax-rs web service** where I pass 2 header parameters `userId` and `adminId` and then I retrieve data from an Oracle Database. The idea with the annotation is that I would time how long certain segments of code take. The `userId` is passed to the annotation and is logged out along with the class and the amount of time it takes for the code to complete.

The problem is that when I added this code it caused one of the guice modules to fail making every other guice module fail in the project.

## Very Basic Code

### Lowest Class called for database calls

```
public class lowestClass {
  public static lowestClass create(final String userId){
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new LowestClassModule(userId));
    return injector.getInstance(lowectClass.class);
  }

  @LogTimerMeasurement
  public DataInfo getDataInfo() {
    //populates a DataInfo object with info from database
  }
}
```

### Lowest Class Module

```
public class lowestClassModule {
  public final String adminId;
  public final String userId;

  public lowestClassModule(final String adminId, final String userId){
    this.adminId = adminId;
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  public lowestClassModule(final String userId){
    this.adminId = "NoAdminId";
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(){
    install(new TimerBindingModule(userId));
  }
}
```

### UpperClass

```
public class upperClass {
  @LogTimerMeasurement
  public DataResponse getDataResponse(){
    //Calls lower class gets DataInfo object and returns DataResponse object
  }

  //Guice module for endpoint
  public static class Module extends AbstractModule{
    private final String adminId;
    private final String userId;

    public Module(final String userId){
      this.adminId = "NoAdminId";
      this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Module(final String adminId, final String userId){
      this.adminId = adminId;
      this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(){
      install(new TimerBindingModule(userId));
      bind(lowestClass.class).toInstance(lowestClass.create(userId));
    }
  }
}
```

### Guice Annotation

#### Annotation Interface

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogTimerMeasurement {

}
```

#### Annotation Interceptor

```
public class LogTimerMeasurementInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    private final String userId;

    public LogTimerMeasurementInterceptor(final String userId){
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        final Method method = invocation.getMethod();
        final String methodName = method.getName();
        final Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();

        final I18N supplyI18n = I18NFactory.createI18N(this.getClass());

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            return invocation.proceed();
        }catch (final Exception e){
            supplyI18n.log(getClass() + "timerError", "\n{0} : {1} :: Unable to log time due to {1}",declaringClass + "." + methodName, userId, e);
            return invocation.proceed();
        }finally {
            final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            supplyI18n.log("timerMessage", "\n{0} : {1} :: Process completed in {2} milliseconds", declaringClass + "." + methodName, userIf, endTime - startTime);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Annotation Module

```
public class TimerBindingModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String userId;

    public TimerBindingModule(final String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(LogTimerMeasurement.class), LogTimerMeasurementInterceptor.create(userId));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the details of the exception you are getting?

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn’t call `invocation.proceed()` in the `catch` block. Since you’re not trying to implement a retry interceptor, you should probably just rethrow the exception.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewPope I noticed that too and it has been fixed the issue ended up being `install(new TimerBindingModule(userId));` can't use this module have to rebind the interceptor class itself